# black regions in cycle rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, collada

While rendering in cycles the supposed rooftops render all black so do the roads, the file is a collada imported from sketchup, I've trided - To solve this just select the object and press tab to go into Edit Mode and press A to select all vertices then press M and choose Merge By Distance.- but with no success.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Can you please provide a .blend file?